# basic Code reading in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

This is a part of android app project, i have got this code I am not able to understand that setOnItemClickListener takes (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) as paramter but the other method void onItemClick is also in paramter space . I am not able to understand that how the object of AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() is calling/using  onItemClick ?

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2Activity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    })
```

Comment: listView is calling the onItemClick through OnItemClickListener Interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: see this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {...}` is an example of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). This is just a shortcut to implelenting `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` [interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and overriding `onItemClick` method manually (it is an [abstract method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)), then instantiating it and passing a reference to it into `setOnItemClickListener` method. Without using an anonymous class, this is what the code looks like:

```
class MyOnItemClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
     * been clicked.
     * <p/>
     * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
     * to access the data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent   The AdapterView where the click happened.
     * @param view     The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
     *                 will be a view provided by the adapter)
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
     * @param id       The row id of the item that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

then instantiating it and assigning it to your `list view`:

```
MyOnItemClickListener clickListener = new MyOnItemClickListener();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not really an Android question - it is more fundamental Java syntax topic. The thing you are referring to is called [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

[`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) method accepts `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` object as an argument. So in order to call `setOnItemClickListener` you need an instance of such listener. One way of getting such an instance - is to create one.

Consider the following example:

```
class MyAwesomeListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //my awesome click handling logic
    }
}


.........
MyAwesomeListener listener = new MyAwesomeListener();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Here I created a custom class class which implements `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` interface. And since it is an instance of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, I can pass this instance as a method argument to `setOnItemClickListener` method.

As an alternative, I could call `setOnItemClickListener` like that:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAwesomeListener());
```

In this case I don't need to create additional variable.

But you can go even further - you can avoid creating custom class which implements `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` by using anonymous class:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //my awesome click handling logic
    }
);
```

So in this case I created a custom implementation of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` right when I set a listener. So this is just a simplified flavor of 2 approaches mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get familiar with anonymous classes.

```
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){...}
```

Creates new, unnamed (anonymous) class implementing `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` listener.
Inside the brackets you just implement method from interface.